# Micronaut Kafka producer, which publishes consumed multicast packets?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x, multicast, micronaut

I am investigating Micronaut's capabilities for some microservices I want to create. One microservice decodes multicast packets (using vertx), and sends them to a local message broker. If I choose to use Micronaut, I realise I would have to switch to Kafka, which is fine.

I've been reading the Micronaut-Kafka documentation, but I seem to be missing a simple piece of the puzzle. I can't work how to (in my case) create a multicast consumer, which then publishes to Kafka via Micronaut. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't think you "have to" use Kafka... Why can't you just make a vanilla Java consumer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's a comment. You could use VertX eventbus. You don't "have to" use Kafka, like you've written